# File Format issue in snowflake - Tilda (Field Delimiter), two double quotes

Tags: escaping, amazon-redshift, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, double-quotes, file-format

We are migrating from red shift to snowflake. There is a table in red shift that is loaded by S3 file. The syntax to load the file to red shift is

```
copy edfenormalisedconfzone.address_1
from 's3://aws-d**/addr**.dat' 
 iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::659**:role/AWS_DUB_**'
delimiter '~' REMOVEQUOTES ACCEPTINVCHARS gzip MAXERROR 1  null as 'NULL' EXPLICIT_IDS;
```

The corresponding command in snowflake is

```
COPY INTO "FLK_DUB_DB_DATALAKE_PRE"."EDFENORMALISEDCONFZONE"."ADDRESS1"
from @FLK_DUB_DB_DATALAKE_PRE.S**.FLK**/SNOWFLAKE/ad**.dat0005_part_00.gz
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV,
FIELD_DELIMITER = '~',
NULL_IF = ('NULL', 'NULL')
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE
COMPRESSION = GZIP
ENCODING = 'UTF8' 
FILE_EXTENSION=DAT)
ON_ERROR = ABORT_STATEMENT;
```

There is no issue in file load to Red-Shift , but file is failing to load in snowflake and upon checking further we found that there is post code field in table that has two double quotes("") after tilda(~)

`enter code here`:47"~""W!U """"""RU""~" "

We are converting from Red Shift file format to Snowflake file format and not sure why this is not working in snowflake.

Comment: try removing `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'` from the snowflake copy command?

Comment: This is not working, Not able to recognize any data types

Comment: When you say it is failing to load, do you mean it gives an error message (in which case please add the error to your question) or the data is loaded into the target table but is incorrect (in which case please show what values do exist in the affected columns)?